# Timer stays at 0 during gameplay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, countdown

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNv1F.png)I am currently adding a countdown timer to my unity game, however the actual numbers do not go down during game play but gradually go down within the inspector panel inside the "Time Left". Does anybody know why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class trackingclicks : MonoBehaviour {

    //static variable added to count users clicks
    //public static int totalclicks=0;
    //"mouseclick" keycode variable to look for mouse click
    public KeyCode mouseclick;
    public float timeLeft;
    public Text timerText;


    //public Transform scoreObj;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        timerText.text = "Time Left:\n" + Mathf.RoundToInt (timeLeft);

    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeLeft < 0) {
            timeLeft = 0;
        }

        timerText.text = "Time Left:\n" + Mathf.RoundToInt (timeLeft);
    }

    void UpdateText () {
        timerText.text = "Time Left:\n" + Mathf.RoundToInt (timeLeft);

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    //void Update () {
    //checks the change in time, aka how much time has passed- bonus time starts at 90
        //clickcontrol.timeBonus -= Time.deltaTime;

        //if (clickcontrol.remainItems == 0) 
        //{
        //  clickcontrol.totalScore += (70 + (Mathf.RoundToInt(clickcontrol.timeBonus)));
            //scoreObj.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = "Score : " + clickcontrol.totalScore;
            //clickcontrol.remainItems = -1;

        //}
    //Check for mouse click
    //if (Input.GetKeyDown (mouseclick)) 
        //{
        //  totalclicks += 1;

    //  }

    //  if (totalclicks >= 5) 
    //  {
    //      Debug.Log ("FAIL!!!");
        //  totalclicks = 0;

    //  }
    //}
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for getting back to me @Programmer, It appears you can see the number however it just sticks at 0 on the screen and does not gradually go down except in the Inspector.

Comment: I have just added a screenshot to the description at the top

Comment: What is the starting value of timeLeft?

Comment: I have set it to 10

Comment: its strange though because when I remove if (timeLeft < 0) { timeLeft = 0;} it will start counting -1, -2, -3 etc

Comment: Can't really tell what's going on. You sure you set it to 10? Is the Editor counting from 10  down? Check if you attached this script to multiple GameObjects by...Select the script, go to Assets --> Find References in Scene. If all fails, you can upload the project somewhere and provide a link to it here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Programmer thank you so much for your help! it works! I just realised the script was also attached to my background game obj, which didn't need to be! I really appreciate your help thank you so much again!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @programmer, if by any chance would you be able to help me add points to my game so that every time I click an object the points will gradually go up. I have been trying this for ages and cant seem to grasp it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Text component is created it's default [`VerticalOverflow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-verticalOverflow.html) value is *Truncate*.

So, when you do:

```
timerText.text = "Time Left:\n" + Mathf.RoundToInt (timeLeft);
```

The *"\n"* will make `Mathf.RoundToInt (timeLeft);` to be written under "Time Left:". The text will not fit the TextBox when you do this.

You have three options:

**1**.Remove the *"\n"*.

**2**.Set the Text's [`VerticalOverflow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-verticalOverflow.html) to Truncate.

This is all you need to do:

```
timerText.verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;
```

**3**.Decrease the Text font from *14* to about *13* or to a lower number.

If you don't want to modify your `Text` so much then **#2** should be used.

**EDIT:**

Make sure that the script is not attached to multiple GameObjects.

Select the script, go to *Assets* --> *Find References in Scene* then remove the duplicated script from other objects.

Comment: You can also check the best fit option of the text to make it always fit the boundaries.